# How to set position of suggestion list in AutoSuggestBox?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a UWP application with a number of AutoSuggestBox controls.

When the suggestion lists open, the drop-down is often positioned at the end of the list or at some random location in the middle. I'd like it to either open to the currently selected item, or open at the top of the list if nothing is selected.

I can't figure out how to control this.

Comment: Do you means that you want the drop-down display on the top of suggest box?

Comment: No, I'm concerned about the scroll position of the contents of the drop-down. My drop down has about 300 items in it. Sometimes the drop down opens to the end of that list, or somewhere in the middle, instead of to the top. I always want it to open at the top.

Answer (score 0):

> How to set position of suggestion list in AutoSuggestBox?

The position was automatically controlled by the available display area, If the bottom area is not enough for dropdown rendering space, it will render top or middle. And it's by design. Currently, we have no such api that use to set the drop-down's placement, if you do want this feature please feel free post your requirement with Windows FeedBackHub app.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not really concerned about the placement of the control in the display though. What I'm talking about is the scroll position of the list of items. Sometimes the list appears with the first item at the top, other times it appears scrolled all the way to the bottom or somewhere in the middle. We sort this list such that the items that the user is most likely to need are at the top, so when the list appears at some other scroll position, it is inconvenient for the user.

Comment: You could order the collection before set it to `ItemSource` and insert the item that matched with AutoSuggestBox text to first.